# Is there an \exclude option?

Tags: include

When I'm debugging a big multifile project, it's often useful to make extensive use of `\includeonly` to narrow down where the problem is. but today I found myself using: `\includeonly{chap1,chap2,chap4,chap5}`. Surely `\exclude{chap3}` would be a simpler way to achieve this functionality? But that particular command doesn't seem to exist. Is there a command with this functionality?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`excludeonly`](http://ctan.org/pkg/excludeonly) package defines an `\excludeonly` command that does what you want. Package description:

> The package defines an `\excludeonly`
>   command, which is (in effect) the
>   opposite of `\includeonly`. If both
>   `\includeonly` and `\excludeonly` exist in
>   a document, only files "allowed" by
>   both will be included.
>
> The package redefines the internal
>   `\@include` command, so it conflicts
>   with packages that do the same.
>   Examples are the classes `paper.cls`
>   (paper) and `thesis.cls` (thesis).

Comment: The link to CTAN is broken on that page. Here is one that works: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/excludeonly/

Comment: I'm actually surprised this is a package, rather than part of the core workings of LaTeX like `\includeonly` is...

Comment: There are other cases like that - `\@addtoreset` is part of the LaTeX kernel, `\@removefromreset` needs (e.g.) the remreset package.

Comment: @Seamus: Remember that in 1993/4 the amount of memory required by LaTeX as it is was already too much for many systems!

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out `\include{chap3}`. The way I understand it, the purpose of `\includeonly` is when you'd like to include just one or two things, it's simpler to use `\includeonly` than to comment out a bunch of lines. But if you're keeping everything and just including one thing, why use a special command just to exclude something?

Comment: That's a bad idea, Aaron, the `\include{chap3}` is needed! Otherwise LaTeX doesn't include `chap3.aux`, and you get lots of undefined references. That's what `\includeonly` is all about: to get the correct references.