# Command \excludeonly for sections

Tags: sections-paragraphs

I understand that there is an `\excludeonly{xyz}` command where `xyz` is a LaTeX file name (explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2845/is-there-an-exclude-option)). This excludes the specified file(s) from compilation. My question is if there is equivalent command for `xyz` being a specific section within a file. So lets say my source latex file (say `source.tex`) is:

```
\usepackage{....}

\begin{document}
\section{Chapter 1}
...

\section{Chapter 2}
...

\section{Chapter 3}
...

\section{Chapter 4}
...

\end{document}
```

and my compiled file (say `thesis.tex`) is:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\input{source}
```

How can I exclude, say Chapter 2, from the compilation process.

Apologies if this has been answered before (I couldn't find it).

Comment: Your example is a little bit confusing. You use `\section`, the titles are `Chapter ...`

Answer (score 1):

You must have separate tex files for each section. Then it is easy for you to exclude chapter2 section. If your code is drawn as shown below then chapter2 tex file will not be compiled.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{excludeonly}
\excludeonly{chap2}
\begin{document}
\include{chap1.tex}

\include{chap2.tex}

\include{chap3.tex}

\include{chap4.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need `\usepackage{excludeonly}` for this